# Error en SELECT con varias tablas CON SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas estoy realizando una consulta query solo con un select con varias tablas este es mi query en la imagen que adjuntare me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DECLARE @Buscar AS VARCHAR(16)
DECLARE @NCuota AS INTEGER

SET @Buscar=('1010100368233')
SET @NCuota= ('8')

SELECT NumeroCredito NroCredito,Moneda,Numero NCuota, CAST(FechaVencimiento AS datetime)as Fec_Vcto, Tb.IDRubro,
                            Descripcion Rubro, Monto_Pactado, Monto_Pagado, Monto_Condonado, 
                            Monto_Descuento, Saldo, Estado_Cuota,Nombres 
                     FROM 
                        (   SELECT Cre.IdCliente,Cli.Nombres,CodigoMoneda Moneda, NumeroCredito,Numero, FechaVencimiento, RubCuo.IDRubro,
                                   Rub.Descripcion, RubCuo.Valor Monto_Pactado, RubCuo.ValorPagado Monto_Pagado, RubCuo.ValorCondonado Monto_Condonado, 
                                   RubCuo.ValorDescuento Monto_Descuento, RubCuo.Saldo, Estado_Cuota=CASE WHEN Cubierta =0 THEN 'Vigente' ELSE 'Cancelado' END
                            FROM BPPROD.CREDITO.DBO.Credito Cre 
                            JOIN  BPPROD. CLIENTE.DBO.vW_Clientes Cli  ON Cre.IDCliente=Cli.IDCliente
                            JOIN BPPROD. CREDITO.DBO.CuotaCredito Cuo ON Cre.IdCredito = Cuo.IdCredito
                            JOIN  BPPROD. CREDITO.DBO.RubroCuotaCredito RubCuo ON Cuo.IdCuotaCredito = RubCuo.IdCuotaCredito
                            JOIN BPPROD. CREDITO.DBO.Rubro Rub  ON RubCuo.IdRubro = Rub.IdRubro
                            WHERE NumeroCredito=''' + CAST(@Buscar AS VARCHAR(16)) + ''' AND Numero=' + CAST(@Ncuota AS VARCHAR(16)) + ' AND Valor<>0 and 
                                  RubCuo.IDRubro not in (41,42,44,45,1056,1057,1058,48,43) 
                        ) Tb
```

Comment: entiendo que la columna `Numero`  es de tipo `smallint` y al comparar con `' + CAST(@Ncuota AS VARCHAR(16)) + '` te sale dicho error. Por ejemplo: `SELECT  CAST('a' AS SMALLINT)`, al ejecutar dicha sentencia te saldrá el error que indicas. `PRIORIDAD DE TIPO DE DATOS` https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190309.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está con esta parte del SQL:

```
WHERE NumeroCredito=''' + CAST(@Buscar AS VARCHAR(16)) + ''' AND Numero=' + CAST(@Ncuota AS VARCHAR(16)) + ' AND Valor<>0 and
```

La verdad es que no entiendo bien por qué estás usando las variables `@Buscar` y `@Ncuota` dentro de comillas de esa manera. De lo que yo puedo ver, puedes usarlos directamente de esta manera:

```
WHERE NumeroCredito= @Buscar AND Numero= @Ncuota AND Valor<>0 and
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan si soluciono te agradesco una consulta: eso esta dentro de un procedimiento almacenado y cuando lo ejecuto se demora como 50 segundos habra alguna manera que dure menos?

Comment: @Pierro: Para mejorar el rendimiento, se necesitaría mucha más información. Si deseas ayuda con esto, te sugiero de hacer una nueva pregunta al respecto, pero asegúrate de incluir en la pregunta la estructura de las tablas y los índices definidas en ellas. También necesitarías incluir el "Actual Execution Plan" de tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la columna Numero, es del tipo smallint, no deberias asignarle un valor VARCHAR a la variable @NCuota. Creo que la solución a tu problema sería el siguiente:

En la declaración

```
SET @NCuota= 8
```

Y en el query:

```
AND Numero= @NCuota
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. aun tengo el problema me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Que tipo de datos tienen las columnas NumeroCredito y Numero?

Comment: Como indica sstan, no veo necesario realizar el CAST. Igualmente quizás en NumeroCredito te esta funcionando porque esa columna es VARCHAR, y la columna Numero, asumo que es un numero, y estas tratando de pasarle un dato VARCHAR....